# GPG constantly throwing "no such file or directory" when doing operations

Tags: macos, command-line, code-signing, gpg

So I want to create a GPG so I can use it. I did `gpg --gen-key`, put in the information but it threw the`No such file or directory` error (see below).

```
❯ gpg --gen-key
gpg (GnuPG) 2.3.1; Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Note: Use "gpg --full-generate-key" for a full featured key generation dialog.

GnuPG needs to construct a user ID to identify your key.

Real name: oof2win2
Email address: a@a.com
You selected this USER-ID:
    "oof2win2 <a@a.com>"

Change (N)ame, (E)mail, or (O)kay/(Q)uit? o
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
gpg: agent_genkey failed: No such file or directory
Key generation failed: No such file or directory
```

So, I went from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330226) and ran `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` and restarted my computer. This still didn't change anything or let it work. So I checked file permissions and got:

`drwx------  15 oof2win2  staff   480B Jun 17 22:42 .gnupg`

700, which looks fine. Set it to 770 and got this, so I think that file permissions are good.

```
❯ gpg --list-keys
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir '/Users/oof2win2/.gnupg'
/Users/oof2win2/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
```

What could be the cause of the GPG issue? I tried reinstalling GPG multiple times, reinstalling my machine but neither worked.

Running Catalina 10.15.7, GPG 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by installing `pinentry-mac` and using that instead of `pinentry`